# Play/pause audio file with javascript command

Tags: javascript

I have some javascript code that gets executed once somebody enters the konami code, and I want it to play if it isn't playind, and pause if it is playing. My code seems to be just wrong. Please help!

```js
var rick = false;
var audio = new Audio('rick_roll.mp3');
var kkeys = [],
  konami = "38,38,40,40,37,39,37,39,66,65,13";
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  kkeys.push(e.keyCode);
  if (kkeys.toString().indexOf(konami) >= 0) {
    $(document).unbind('keydown', arguments.callee);
    if (rick == false) {
      rick = true;
      audio.play();
    } else if (rick == true) {
      rick = false;
      audio.stop();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: What's not working? Can you put together a jsfiddle?

Comment: @Louy I am sorry. What is that?

Comment: A demo I mean. https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @Louy It's on my website. [here](http://www.redstonegaming.com) Just do 'up, up, down, down, left, right, left, right, b, a, enter'

Comment: It's working for me. Which browser are you using?

Comment: @Louy, you can play and pause it? Enev while playing, you can then pause it when you repeat the code?

Comment: Oh, no it doesn't. I see the problem now. I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing something like this:

```js
var rick = false;
var audio = new Audio('rick_roll.mp3');
var kkeys = [],
  konami = "38,38,40,40,37,39,37,39,66,65,13";
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  kkeys.push(e.keyCode);
  if (kkeys.toString().indexOf(konami) >= 0) {
    kkeys = []; // <-- Change here
    if (rick == false) {
      rick = true;
      audio.play();
    } else if (rick == true) {
      rick = false;
      audio.pause(); // <-- another issue
    }
  }
});
```

You're unbinding the event listener after you get the code entered. You should instead clean old data and start waiting for it again.

Comment: That's another issue. It's because there's no such thing as `audio.stop()`. Change that to `audio.pause()`. It works for me.

Comment: Still not working...var rick = false;
var audio = new Audio('rick_roll.mp3');
var kkeys = [],
  konami = "38,38,40,40,37,39,37,39,66,65,13";
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  kkeys.push(e.keyCode);
  if (kkeys.toString().indexOf(konami) >= 0) {
    kkeys = []; // <-- Change here
    if (rick == false) {
      rick = true;
      audio.play();
    } else if (rick == true) {
      rick = false;
      audio.pause();
    }
  }
});

Comment: Works for me on FF and Chrome on the website - both playing and pausing.

Comment: @Louy I tworks now, but how can i 'reset' the time where it paused to 0/restart the song?

Comment: You can use `audio.currentTime = 0;` as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/currentTime).